# How to compare value in two columns in FuelPHP

Tags: sql, orm, fuelphp

I have problem when query table using FuelPHP 1.3's Model.
Entries table have three columns ('id', 'status', 'current', 'max' ).

```
$result = Model_Entry::query()
    ->where('status', 1)
    ->where('count_current', '>=', 'count_max');
```

I want to use 'where' method's third argument as column name, but it handled as value in generated query.

Example

```
SELECT * FROM `entries` AS `t0` WHERE `t0`.`status` = 1 AND `t0`.`count_current` >= 'count_max'
```

My Goal

```
SELECT * FROM `entries` AS `t0` WHERE `t0`.`status` = 1 AND `t0`.`count_current` >= `t0`.`count_max`
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what you want, you have to use [DB::expr()](http://fuelphp.com/dev-docs/classes/database/db.html#/method_expr)

So, your code will be:

```
$result = Model_Entry::query()
    ->where('status', 1)
    ->where('count_current', '>=', DB::expr('count_max'));
```